# linq to entities group by sub-query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, group-by, subquery

I have the following code:

```
var statements = db.statement
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.id)
                .Take(5)
                .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(d => new Statements
                             {
                                 Accounts = d.statement_entry.AsEnumerable()
                                     .GroupBy(b => b.currency)
                                     .Select(b =>
                                             new Account
                                                 {
                                                     In = b.Where(l => l.amount > 0).Sum(l => l.amount),
                                                     Out = b.Where(l => l.amount < 0).Sum(l => l.amount),
                                                     Balance = b.Sum(l => l.amount),
                                                     Currency = b.Key
                                                 }).OrderBy(b => b.Currency),
                                 UploadedDate = d.uploaded_date,
                                 Id = d.id
                             })
                .ToList();
```

Is there a way that I could do it without the `AsEnumerable()`? From what I understand the `AsEnumberable` will cause a query to take place for each of the `statement`s returned.

Or is there a better way to refactor the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand wrongly. `AsEnumerable` will make the query execute on the local (client) machine.

This

```
statements = db.statement
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.id)
            .Take(5)
```

will be executed on the (SQL) server,

the remaining part on the client

Why are you puttin the `AsEnumerable`? I think the query should work even without (and it would do everything server-side)

The only thing is that after the `OrderBy(b => b.Currency)` you should put a `.ToList()` so that the `.Select(b => new Account` is materialized and cached.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first `.AsEnurmerable` seems necessary, but you were right about the second. Adding a `.ToList` gave an exception: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.`

Comment: @paulslater19 Sadly each IQueryable provider is different from the others, and then everything depends on how you have configured the DBML.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks for the help. Things don't seem to be running slowly. Hope that continues to be the case as the dataset increases.